# Can't set default value for ICommand of an DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, icommand

I want to call an `UserControl`'s Command from any viewmodel. I tried to bind to the Command in my view but it didn't work.

(I don't have enough reputation to post images, so [here is a link to the image representation of my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHK03.png) )

**View.xaml**

```
<controls:SafeBox
                Height="30"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                ShowCapsLockAlert="True"
                ShowCopyCommand = "True"
                CopyCommand="{Binding CopyCommandInVM}"
                AllowClipboardCommands ="True"
                WaterMark ="Enter your master password"/>
```

This way I just want to access SafeBox's CopyCommand programmatically.

**ViewModel.cs**

```
#region [Command] CopyCommandInVM
public ICommand CopyCommandInVM
{
    get
    {
        return _copyCommandInVM;
    }
    set
    {
        CopyCommandInVM = value;
    }
}
private ICommand _copyCommandInVM;

#endregion
```

That way I can just I want to call UserControl's CopyCommand in my viewmodel like this: `CopyCommandInVM.Execute(null)`;

**UserControl.xaml**

```
#region [Dependency Property] CopyCommand
public static readonly DependencyProperty CopyCommandProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("CopyCommand",
typeof(ICommand),
typeof(SafeBox),
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
{
    DefaultValue= new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(Copy)),
    DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger=UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
}
);

[Bindable(true)]
[Category("Command")]
public ICommand CopyCommand
{
    get
    {
        return (ICommand)GetValue(CopyCommandProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        this.SetValue(CopyCommandProperty, value);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Static field, calls the Copy()
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj"></param>
private static void Copy(object sender)
{
    /* Not working:
    var holder = obj as SafeBox; 
    holder.Copy();
    how can I make it work or come up with another solution
    to reach the holder of the dependency property (and call the method belown) */
}

/// <summary>
/// Copies the content of the SafeBox
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj"></param>
private void Copy()
{
    //...
}
#endregion
```

My attempt did not work, I can't reach the command in the UserControl.

I've looked around internet before asking and could not find one good example for bindable commands (with default values). I don't want to use any MVMM libraries.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit :**

Here is my scenerio:

1. I mostly use my UserControl without binding to this Command property.

   `ViewModel` [unaware of this command] **=>**
   `View` [unaware  of this command] **=>**
   `UserControl` [execuses the default value of this command]
2. But for one case I need to call this command(`CopyCommand`) of
   `UserControl` from another `ViewModel`. I try to stick to the MVMM
   pattern so my `ViewModel` shouldn't be aware of the `View` but call
   this command via `binding` to it and calling
   `BindedToChangeVisibility.Execute();`.

   `ViewModel` [`CopyOfCopyCommand.Execute(null)`] **=>**
   `View` [`CopyCommand={Binding CopyOfCopyCommand`} ] **=>**
   `UserControl` [runs the `CopyCommand` (default value)]

Comment: can you use null and in the constructor set the default value?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea. I've tried that but it kills the binding. I mean if I bind to the command of this usercontrol outside like `ChangeVisibilityCommand={Binding AnotherCommandFromVM}` then AnotherCommandFromVM does not take the command that I've set on user controls constructor.

Comment: Setting a command property by a binding would always replace any previously set command. Two-way binding and hence also UpdateSourceTrigger don't make sense here. There is no hidden magic in a two-way binding that would keep both the old and the new command in one property.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but I'm still confused. I've almost completed my first wpf/mvmm desktop application, even though I thought I could do the basics, I think I'm still failing to understand the system. I need to have an ICommand property with default value, that can be executed by another ViewModel (via binding to user controls `ICommand` and calls `Execute()`. Updated the question.

Comment: What you are trying to do actually ? Explain with a figure if posible.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/i3R5Y3O.png , updated the question too.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a UserControl recently and faced the same problem. I created a 
Class-Library for all UserControl relevant classes etc. which then will be added to the main project.

In order to solve your problem, I have created an own command class called
(in my case) DropDownControlCommands, which contained all of the ICommands with the implementation.

I then bound some of the events, that i needed to use in my project, to the DropDownControl and to the Control (in your case the button).

Of course that's not the best solution, but it works great and both
controls have the exact same command/operation.

If you use this solution, I would suggest you, that you add your "DropDownControlCommands"-Class (however it may be called then) to a class library, which also contains your control.

That makes it seem a bit more structured and it is great if you want to use your control again in another project.

I hope I could help. Unfortunately, I haven't found a better solution yet.